# Wordpress: Is it possible to have 2 forms on the same page that use $index and $value for input fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have two checkbox forms on the same page. When they are both there, the second form will not work. I'm wondering if there is a way to have both on the same page with them both needing the `$index` of the input.

The input fields are similar to this (the other is unchecked):

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='$index' onChange='this.form.submit()' checked='checked'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='itemDELETE$index' value='$bookID'>";
```

This is the other

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='$index' onChange='this.form.submit()'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='itemADD$index' value='$bookID'>";
```

And the data is stored like:

```
$value = $_POST["check"][0];
$toDELETE = $_POST["itemDELETE" . $value];
```

and

```
$value = $_POST["checkbox"][0];
$toADD = $_POST["itemADD" . $value];
```

I have tried renaming `$value` but the issue lies in the `$index` on the input fields.

They are outputting correctly, but the second one will not store the value properly in it's variable, whereas the first does. The second is the delete one.

When I remove the first forms functionality, the second form works. But when I add it back, the second one stops working. Not picking up on the `itemDELETE $value`

If I manually put the value in like this `"itemDELETE0"` instead of `["itemDELETE" . $value]`it works. But I need the $value to picked up on since it's a foreach loop.

Comment: Are you sure that is syntax you are really using? `value='$index'` will be showing the value as `$index` because it is not PHP echo.

Comment: So sorry! I have updated it, I am using echo for the form inputs, I didn't think to include that originally. I apologize for that! And thank you for commenting! @vee

Comment: https://onlinephp.io/c/88129 This seems to be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this was to put the second form in different shortcode, and include it on the page. It works well and doesn't clash. Same code, just in a different shortcode.

Then on the page created, I used the shortcode for the first form and then put the shortcode for the second form below it.

And instead of defaulting it to checked, I had to use it unchecked. But that works alright.